# Python paho mqtt throw Type Error: "an integer is required"

Tags: python, mqtt

I have five raspberry pi 3 to collect IOT data. Only one client throw this error,

Here is the traceback message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./uploadRecordDegree.py", line 57, in <module>
    auth=auth, client_id=client_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/publish.py", line 232, in single
    protocol, transport, proxy_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/publish.py", line 167, in multiple
    client.connect(hostname, port, keepalive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 941, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1119, in reconnect
    return self._send_connect(self._keepalive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2647, in _send_connect
    self._pack_str16(packet, self._client_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2496, in _pack_str16
    packet.extend(data)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Here is my test code:

```
BOX = {"1234": "balabala"}
host = "192.168.10.11"
port = 1883
topic = "iot/device"
auth = {'username': 'xxxx','password': 'xxxxx'}
payload = json.dumps(BOX) 
client_id = "testNode"
publish.single(topic, payload, qos=1, hostname=host, port=port,
        auth=auth, client_id=client_id)
```

My Python version is 3.5.2
paho-mqtt version is 1.5.1

Each client is in the same paho-mqtt version, same code.
I cant figure out what's the problem going.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you out.

Comment: Apart from the username/password is it that EXACT code that produces that error?

Comment: @hardillb Yes, 
Apart from the username/password, I can re-produce the error with this code.